# Создать свою кодировку

Tags: python, кодировка

Каким образом можно создать свою кодировку?
Например, Я создаю алфавит из четырех букв, с такой кодировкой в цифрах:

```
A:01, B:110, C:001, D:00
```

11001001 — BAC

Как можно увидеть, при такой кодировке может быть несколько вариантов раскодировки.

Может есть уже какие-то готовые решения, которые решают эту проблему?

Comment: А почему именно такая кодировка? Двух двоичных знаков достаточно, чтобы закодировать однозначно 4 символа: 00, 01, 10, 11. Либо делают фиксированное кол-во битов (так проще), либо какие-то стоп-биты придумывают и т.д.

Comment: Читайте https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code и в частности https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Прочитайте про условие фано https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE если коротко - Никакое кодовое слово не может быть началом другого кодового слова. В случаем, который вы привели в качестве примера C (001) начинается с кода D (00), из-за этого получается несколько вариантов дешифровки

Comment: @zankorobos "Никакое кодовое слово не может быть началом другого кодового слова" - это достаточное условие, но не необходимое. У меня в ответе есть вариант алфавита, где сие условие не соблюдено: ABCD: 1, 10, 100, 1000 Но коллизий возникать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не было коллизий:

- 00, 01, 10, 11;
- 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000;
- 1, 10, 100, 1000;
- 0, 10, 110, 111.

и их "зеркальные" 1->0, 0->1 наборы.

Еще есть вариант кодирования количеством знаков и чередованием: A - 1, B - 2, C - 3, D - 4.

Тогда

- ABCD - 0110001111 или 1001110000 (0 11 000 1111 и 1 00 111 0000)
- AAAA - 0101 ИЛИ 010
- BBCC - 0011000111 или 1100111000
- DDDD - 0000111100001111 или 1111000011110000

Можно так:

- все записывается группами по 5 байт
- 2-5 байты - это наличие A-D
- 1-й байт - порядок следования

Тогда ABBDDCA запишется 011000010111011:

- ABBDDCA
- AB BD DCA
- AB00 0B0D DC0A
- 0AB00 00B0D 1A0CD
- 01100 00101 11011

Иногда выбор разных изощренных методов дает то или иное преимущество. Но в общем случае, при равномерном распределении самыми "компактными"  будут алфавиты из 3-х и 2-х символов - обычные троичная и двоичная системы счисления. (Равномерное распределение - это очень мутное понятие, но условно: для длины строки кратной кол-ву символов алфавита (n) вероятность встретить символ = `1/n` у всех.  И порядок в группе из `n` штук тоже равновероятен. Если по-умному, то "энтропия стремится к бесконечности").

Но главный вопрос, для чего это вам? Зная конечную цель, можно выбрать\придумать более подходящий вариант.